# can I create a project from my web site url

Tags: web, copy, project

I am just starting with Aptana and I don't have the original HTML files for my web site.  Is there a way that I can import my whole web site as a project or do I have to open each page from with Aptana and save with the original urls?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use Interachy which is a commercial Mac option. One open source Windows program is [HTTrack](http://download.cnet.com/HTTrack-Website-Copier/3000-2377_4-10039773.html).

If your site isn't large, it's often feasible to go through page by page and save each one as source. You also need to save all the images and CSS files, and reconstruct the folder directories, though it's goes faster than you might think.

Good luck!